# How to run .py directly in a python package?

Tags: python

I am working on transformer and I am interested in one of the models and would like to run the source code.

For example, in the T5 model file, such import appears.

```
from ...activations import ACT2FN
from ...file_utils import (
DUMMY_INPUTS,
DUMMY_MASK,
add_start_docstrings,
add_start_docstrings_to_model_forward,
is_torch_fx_proxy,
replace_return_docstrings,
)
```

activations.py and file_utiles.py are two python file in this transformers fold.

But it always gives:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: The way I currently do it is to copy the package and later call the required python files from the original package.

The changes are made in the copied package.

Comment: Is the code snippet from your own file or from source code of some python package from PyPI?